# Envion token show up as ENV instead of EVN?

Tags: myetherwallet, ico

I invested in the Envion ICO today. After the ETH transaction to them was confirmed the tokens showed up in MEW but as "ENV" instead of "EVN". What i found env is something completely different, envions smart contract does state "EVN"

Also, no ENV/EVN show up in ethplorer.io in my wallet (but other tokens do). Is this an issue because the ICO has not ended yet or what can this whole mess be?

Many thanks

Comment: First make sure you have contributed to the correct address. Sometimes block explorer, wallets do not immediately recognize a new token.

Comment: There is still ENV instead of EVN in MyEtherWallet. What i have to do? Thank You!

Comment: The developers will need to deploy this version first. So it is not in our hands now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18334)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there might be a typo in MyEtherWallet's token definitions, which is why it's showing as `ENV`.

In [`tokens-eth--small.json`](https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/ethereum-lists/blob/03839ea72f31565aa1cadb9edde0c5d4568c92f7/tokens/tokens-eth--small.json)

```
"symbol"      : "ENV",
"address"     : " 0xd780Ae2Bf04cD96E577D3D014762f831d97129d0",
"decimals"    : 18,
"name"        : "Envion AG"
```

And [`tokens-eth.json`](https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/ethereum-lists/blob/03839ea72f31565aa1cadb9edde0c5d4568c92f7/tokens/tokens-eth.json):

```
"symbol"      : "ENV",
"address"     : "0xd780Ae2Bf04cD96E577D3D014762f831d97129d0",
"decimals"    : "18",
"name"        : "Envion AG",
"ens_address" : "",
"website"     : "https://envion.org",
"logo": {
  "src"       : "",
  "width"     : "",
  "height"    : "",
  "ipfs_hash" : ""
},
.....
```

The address that MEW is using to find the contract is correct though, so it's just a UI issue. [Contract is [here](https://etherscan.io/token/0xd780ae2bf04cd96e577d3d014762f831d97129d0#readContract) (EtherScan link).]

**Edit:** Opened issue [#357](https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/ethereum-lists/issues/357) to get it fixed.

**Edit#2:** For your second query, you could try checking the balance of your address on EtherScan's [token portal](https://etherscan.io/token/0xd780ae2bf04cd96e577d3d014762f831d97129d0#balances) (in the "Search/Filter By" box).

Comment: Thanks so much Richard for this excellent answer. Found it via your hint with the token portal and it really seems to just be an UI issue.

Comment: I commited the changes, waiting for the pull request to go through. Thanks again.

Comment: Brilliant - glad we got it sorted so speedily :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I wrote to them. They wrote back. Anybody who paid in BTC or credit card will be emailed soon on how they can transfer their tokens to their ether wallets. ETH buyers can do it immediately. Nevertheless, your ENV balance should reflect in your Envoin login. That's gurantee enough. Cheers!